# TeamCity, Maven Build not found child module

Tags: maven, svn, teamcity, pom.xml

I've Maven project with one subproject, when I run my install task on parent project from IDEA (IntelliJ IDEA) all works fine and **maven** resolve child module.

My projects are versioned on **subversion**, and this is the filesystem structure:

```
project
|--pom.xml
|--subproject
   |
   |-- branches
   |-- tags
   |-- trunk (here there is my subproject source, also pom.xml file)
```

I've create project with its subproject, from svn URL, on **teamcity** server.

When I run Build on parent project it fail and return me the following error:

```
[Step 1/1] Error reading Maven project: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Child module /opt/buildAgent/work/ee114e0c77ee2c44/subproject of /opt/buildAgent/work/ee114e0c77ee2c44/pom.xml does not exist @
```

How can I say to parent-project-build where it find the child module?

Is there something else wrong?

Parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>MyProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>Foo</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Child POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.company.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.company.subproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>subproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>subproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

**EDIT:**
I added new parameter (pathSubproject) to my parent pom.xml, so when I run the parent build it skipped the previous error, but now it crash when trying to resolve parent dependency on the subproject. So I added a new parameter also at subproject (parentPath) and I passed it to relativePath inside parent tag.

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact it.company.project:MyProject:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath'
```

I think that my subproject POM not resolve the properties that I put inside `<relativePath` tag.

Is possible pass a properties to `relativePath` tag?

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by creating 2 `profile` in my parent pom, the first one builds the parent application with all submodules, while the latter build only the the parent application.

In TeamCiTY build configuration settings I specified (inside **Additional Maven command line parameters**) the profile that build only parent module, and after I built the parent Application.

After that I built the parent application I built all submodules, and then I was able to build parent application with all modules.

I'm not sure that this is the right way, but in my case it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<modules/>` section of your parent project's pom, each module listed is a relative path to the directory containing the module.

So if you don't want to change the directory structure, you should be able to refer to the trunk of your subproject using `<module>subproject/trunk</module>`.

This does seem a bit clumsy though.  If you are using the aggregator / modules pattern, I would recommend that `project` and `subproject` are both in the same SVN respository.  If that isn't appropriate, then your `subproject` might not really be a module, and should be a dependency or have `project` as its parent artifact.

Comment: My project and subproject are both in the same SVN repository, and the structure of the repository is as shown in my Question. I prefer devide my main develop line to the other branches line, so for each subproject I created 3 subfolders: trunk, tags and branches.

Comment: Ok, then using subproject/trunk for the module should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: I added new parameter (pathSubproject) to my parent pom.xml, so when I run the parent build it skipped the previous error, but now it crash when trying to resolve parent dependency on the subproject. This is the error `The project it.company.project:Subproject:3.0 (/opt/buildAgent/work/ee114e0c77ee2c44/subproject/trunk/pom.xml) has 1 error`

Comment: Can I pass a properties to `<relativePath>` tag?

Comment: No idea, what happens when you try it?  If I was you, I would try to get it working with hardcoded values, then once it works, start factoring out the values into properties.

Comment: With the hardcoded values it works fine, when I use property the `relativePath` tag is ignored.